Display statement qualifiers with SPARQL request to wikibase
I am new to SPARQL and trying to use a query to obtain not just items and a statement, but also a qualifier that comes with that statement.
Here is the idea: entities in the wikibase are political parties (Q2) and their receive public funding (P92). Along with the amount of public funding, as a qualifier, is a subsection of that funding (public funding is provided in two blocks, that's one of them).
So far, I have the following:
SELECT ?itemLabel ?publicfunding ?mepfunding
WHERE {  
  ?item epfowdt:P9 epfowd:Q2 ; #the item is a political party
        epfowdt:P92 ?publicfunding #that political party has received public funding
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en-gb". } 
}
ORDER BY ?itemLabel

Here is a link to that query.
What I am missing is the way to display the "mepfunding" element (P62).
Surely this is quite basic but... any ideas?

getting the statement and then the attached value as well as it's qualifier needs just other namespaces as well as an additional hop in the graph: SELECT ?itemLabel ?publicfunding ?mepfunding WHERE {     ?item epfowdt:P9 epfowd:Q2 ;         epfop:P92 ?publicfunding_stmt .   ?publicfunding_stmt epfops:P92 ?publicfunding ;                epfopq:P62 ?mepfunding   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en-gb". }  } ORDER BY ?itemLabel

Thank you so much @UninformedUser! This is super useful!!

I know it's difficult in the beginning, if it helps for another Wikbase instance called Wikidata you can see the relationships among statements and the like visualized here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/WIKIDATA_Qualifiers,_References_and_Ranks#/media/File:SPARQL_data_representation.png and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/WIKIDATA_Qualifiers,_References_and_Ranks#/media/File:Rdf_mapping-vector.svg - the prefixes are indeed different, but technically it should be just without the suffic epfo and then match your schema

Thanks, I'll make sure to go through those links!
